# Change Xcode file path to absolute

Tags: xcode, xcode6, filepath

I have tried to duplicate my Xcode project, however I am having issues with my changes in the new project effecting the original project too.

I was looking at a video of how to duplicate a project and noticed that in the File Inspector, their 'Location' was greyed out and set to absolute, and had the correct file path of the new project. Mine however is set to relative to workspace and has the original file path.

[image]

Anyone have any idea how I can change this to absolute? I don't have the option.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you duplicate the project? It's usually `absolute` by default.

Comment: I did it through Finder and just used cmd + D and renamed the folder.

Comment: @l'L'l I discovered that it is `absolute` in the `.xcodeproj` file, but I have to use `.xcworkspace` as I am using Pods.

Comment: When you change it in the `xcodeproj` does it resolve the issue? If so you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Strangely, it doesn't fix it. When I go back to the `.xcworkspace`, it's still set to the original path.

Comment: That behavior seems incorrect; I would suggest filing that as a bug. I'll upvote your question too :)